# AVCaptureDevice returning nil

Tags: cocoa, avcapturedevice

I'm having an issue here trying to get any capture device input port on OS X.  Specifically for audio (for example built in mic).  Here's the code I'm running.

```
NSArray * devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
NSLog(@"devices = %li", devices.count);
```

The output for that is always 0.  Now if I create an AVCaptureScreenInput port I can manage to get that to work, but I can't get audio with it.  The ultimate goal is to record the screen and also capture audio at the same time.  The problem is getting the audio port.

Comment: How stupid of me.  Sandboxing was on and Microphone was not checked.  I hope my stupidity helps someone else here.

Comment: Please add your own answer as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How stupid of me. Sandboxing was on and Microphone was not checked. I hope my stupidity helps someone else here.

Comment: It's also good to mention that it will not work on the simulator, only on actual devices.